# Does iterator support + operator?

Tags: c++, stl

I saw the following code used to delete one selected element from `std::vector`:

```
vector<hgCoord>::iterator it;
int iIndex = 0;
    const int iSelected = 5;
for( it = vecPoints.begin(); it != vecPoints.end(); ++it, ++iIndex )
{
    if( iIndex == iSelected )
    {
        vecPoints.erase( it );
        break;
    }
}
```

I argue that this code is not efficient and should be written as follows:

```
vector<hgCoord>::iterator it;
int iIndex = 0;
    const int iSelected = 5; // we assume the vector has more than 5 elements.

    vecPoints.erase( vecPoints.begin() + iSelected );
```

However, I am not sure whether or not this code is following the C++ STL standard.

Comment: You are correct, since `std::vector<T>::iterator` is a `RandomAccessIterator` (a.k.a. `T*`).  Just remember that if you have less than 5 elements in your vector, your second algorithm will fail.

Comment: If those prefix-`i`'s are a form of Hungarian Notation, I strongly object to either piece of code.

Comment: @eq-: what, because `i` should be used as a prefix meaning `iterator`, you mean ;-p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make this code generic, so it works no matter whether the iterator supports `operator +`, and uses the most efficient available implementation:

```
template <typename C>
void erase_at(C& container, typename C::size_type index) {
    typename C::iterator i = container.begin();
    std::advance(i, index);
    container.erase(i);
}
```

Internally, `std::advance` uses `operator +` if the iterator type supports it. Otherwise (e.g. for `std::list<>::iterator`) it advances the iterator one step at a time in a loop, just like the first code you posted.

Comment: In response to a comment on dirbeas' deleted answer - I think the reason `std::advance` modifies its argument is something to do with the fact that because it's very type-agnostic, in particular it works on all InputIterators, which are *cheap* but *dangerous* to copy. When used with an iterator that might be only an InputIterator, not a ForwardIterator, you can't safely use the old value ever again, so even if it did return an iterator, you would still only use it as `i = std::advance(i,n);`, or on a temporary as in dribeas' code. Returning `void` helps prevent stupidity. Sometimes. Maybe.

Answer (score 10):

Random-access iterators support addition and subtraction, and `std::vector` iterators are random-access.

Answer (score 2):

You argue correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine for a vector because vector iterators are random access iterators, so it's OK to add an offset as you have done. The same won't work for some other container types (such as deque or map).

So, your code is better for a vector, but the other code may have been intended to work with other types of container.

Comment: Actually, `deque` uses random access iterators too.

Comment: I think the modified code works for vector, string, and deque.

Comment: @Fred Larson: Oops! I don't know why I typed deque, I meant list! Thanks for the correction.